# Inverse Function Theorem: is this true?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

The inverse function theorem is usually stated as follows:

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a smooth map and let $x_0$ be a point such that $\det J_f (x_0) \neq 0$. Then there exists an open set $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ containing $x_0$ such that $f: f \to f(U)$ is a diffeomorphism.

> Is the following an equivalent statement? Or is it false?

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be open and $f:U \to \mathbb R^n$ be smooth and such that  $\det J_f (u) \neq 0$ for all $u \in U$. Then $f:U \to f(U)$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: No, there's no reason it should be an injection.

Comment: To give a concrete example in support of @MikeMiller's comment - Take $z\mapsto z^2$ in $U$ = the complex plane minus the origin. The real version of this is $(x,y)\mapsto (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$, and the determinant of the jacobian matrix = $4 (x^2 + y^2)$, so vanishes nowhere on $U$, but squaring is not injective.

Comment: Any covering provides a counterexample. For example you can take $t\mapsto (cos t, sin t)$ as a map from $\mathbb R$ to $S^1$.